# Rails: Scope that includes a datetime query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to define a `scope` that includes all items that haven't yet expired - or that don't have an expiry date at all (`nil`).

Here's what I have, but it doesn't return what I want:

```
scope :active, -> { where(["expires > ? OR expires = ?", Time.now, nil]) }
```

I'm new to Rails, so is there something obvious that I'm missing (or perhaps a glaring syntax error)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a special syntax when comparing `NULL` values. Try it like this:

```
scope :active, -> { where("expires > ? OR expires IS NULL", Time.zone.now) }
```

I also changed `Time.now` to `Time.zone.now` so that it uses your app's configured time zone.

Comment: Yup, the `IS NULL` fixed it! Thanks .. any idea why the one I used didn't work? I checked the log and it was translated to `WHERE (expires > '2014-07-24 10:22:13' OR expires = NULL`. So the only difference is that pesky `IS`..

Comment: The problem is that NULL values are treated as "unknown values". As such, comparing NULL with another NULL (that's what the `=` operator does) yields yet another NULL - NULL is not equal to NULL.